# Is this possible to restrict backward relationship lookup in the core model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Is this possible to restrict (filter) objects on the level of the core model so that none of the related models is able to see the unfiltered results?

Let the example be provided:

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().exclude(deleted__isnull=False)

class User(models.Model):
    objects = UserManager()
    ...

class Report(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User, ....)
    ...
```

I expected this to be working the following way: Report.users will not show record where *deleted* is not null. But actually, they are shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the results as below, if you have a booleanlfield deleted in your model

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(deleted=False)
```

Comment: Is it any different from what I wrote? I don't think so. I guess there is no possibility for such a restriction because the related models retrieve the objects from the DB directly.